# Can not change debug environment automatically on visual studio code with config

Tags: visual-studio-code

For example, my root workstation directory is `/home/chain/Project`. And I have two separate projects which is `python` and `website`. My `launch.json` goes:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": 
[
    {
        "name": "Python",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "pythonPath": "${config:python.pythonPath}",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/python_project_source/test.py",
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}/python_project_source",
        "env": {},
        "envFile": "${workspaceRoot}/.env",
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput"
        ]
    },
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "url": "${workspaceRoot}/website/test.html",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/website"
    }
]
```

}

As expected when I select `test.py` and press 'F5' it can switch to python debug environment, and when I select `test.html` the Chrome will be opened.

The fact is, VS code only remember the environment I debugged last time rather than change it automatically. So the only thing I do now is adding some comments to one environment (`/* */`) when I need to compile the other.:(

Is there something wrong in my `launch.json`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Automatically switching the debug environment based on the file (or file-type) is not a current feature of Visual Studio Code, I believe.

You'll have to manually switch the launch configuration depending on the type of debugging task you want to perform.

And, of course, you could consider writing a feature request: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode

Comment: Really? Haha! Now that it can not be counted as a big problem, I think i will write a request. Thanks!

Comment: Is there anything ongoing regarding file type debug switcher? I use `python` and `bash` debug during the day and have to change manually the debugger, which hurts.